# Change the countryCode for Siren Cocoapod

Tags: swift, xcode, siren

Using [Siren with Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Siren) :

> [Siren Error] Error retrieving App Store data as the JSON results were empty. Is your app available in the US? If not, change the `countryCode` variable to fix this error.

This is the error I'm getting when I'm using Siren and my app is not available in US.
How to change my country code in Siren ?

Comment: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren/blob/dbfe20032f6d88ff3bf5c7edb64eab8d07d0af29/Sources/Managers/APIManager.swift ? Looking for `countryCode` in the project should lead you to it. Don't use the default one, create your own with your own country code.

Comment: thanks for ur help @Larme .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the country code as follows:

```
let siren = Siren.shared
siren.apiManager = APIManager(countryCode: "RU")
```

This helps alleviate all the issues you might have. There were also some issues with Apple changing the JSON types, but it should have been fixed already